# Can elbow curve for kNN be linear?

Tags: python

I just plotted the elbow curve for kNN and it is negative linear line. X_axis -> n_neighbours and Y_axis -> error.

```
def elbow(k):
    test_error = []
    for i in k:
        test_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
        test_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
        pred_i = test_model.predict(X_test)
        test_error.append(np.mean(pred_i != Y_test))
    return test_error
k = (1,100)
plt.plot(k,test_model)
plt.xlabel('n_neighbours')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.title('Elbow curve')
```

elbow curve that I got:

[image: elbow curve that I got]

Comment: It doesn't seem like you ever call the `elbow` function...

Comment: Did you mean `k = list(range(1, 100))`?, Because with `k = (1, 100)` you're only testing for the two values `1` and `100`.

Comment: I did call the elbow function @ForceBru

Comment: @AniruddhaPurohitMadhusudhan, the code you posted doesn't call it

Comment: Maybe you could reduce the k size and check, and you for loop needs to be range(k)

Comment: Thank you guys. But I got something like this. https://imgelbowcrve.blogspot.com/2021/12/blog-post.html

Comment: You are defining the model inside the elbow function but you try to print it outside of the function. What I think you are trying to do is to print the average error for every model with the hyperparameter n_neighbours in range(k). You need to run the function, store the results and then you can print them for range(k)